# The application PIANO

Tags: app-store-connect, piano

When logging into iTunes Connect, after creating a new user, to test it, I get this message:

You do not have access to the application PIANO. Contact us.

What does this mean?

Comment: It means you should do what the message says and contact them.

Comment: That happened to me too. In my case, it was something about lack of permissions (nothing to do with a PIANO app at all). Maybe the user doesn't still have access. You could review the permission granting process.

Comment: Not true unfortunately. I have access to everything else. But I can't access sales and trends being logged in as the administrator. I created a new account with permissions - doesn't matter. I can't access via PC or Mac. The best response it says in the message is that Apple will get back to you within 3 business days and try to decipher what is going on.

Comment: I am also having this problem.  Ken White's comment would be useful if it were actually possible to contact them.  When I click on the link it simply takes me to a place where it ask me several questions (none of which answer my problem) and then makes me start over.  At no time am I afforded the opportunity to actually contact them.

Comment: I also have the same issue, but it is not possible to contact apple. I just go round and round in an endless loop of questions. Regarding the Medico, White and Stocker above who want to decide what is a relevant question or not.. Please guys let us get answers to our questions instead of being the gatekeepers and trying to decide for us what is a relevant question and what is not.

Comment: I also got the same issue with admin account. admin account supposed to have privilage to run ALL modules. My efforts to contact apple was also a waste of time. they just redirect you to "contact us" page which only is an automated faq.

Answer (score 0):

I got the message in Chrome for Mac after upgrading to OSX Yosemite.  It did work fine when I logged into itunesconnect in Safari.  When I opened developer tools on Chrome, I see a 403 forbidden returning from the server on that resources, so it was a legit permissions issue.  I logged out of itunesconnect, then logged back in and it worked fine.